# Numpy matrix must be 2-dimensional error

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
def J(x, y):
    return np.matrix([[8-(4 * y), -4 * y], [y, -5 + x]])

x_0 = np.matrix([[1], [1]])
test = J(x_0[0], x_0[1])
```

When I go to run it I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "broyden.py", line 15, in <module>
    test = J(x_0[0][0], x_0[1][0])
  File "broyden.py", line 12, in J
    return np.matrix([[8-(4 * y), -4 * y], [y, -5 + x]])
  File "/home/collin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 261, in __new__
    raise ValueError("matrix must be 2-dimensional")
ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Everything appears to be 2-d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `x_0[0]` is still `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix`, not a scalar value.
You need get a scale value to treat as a matrix element. Try this code

```
test = J(x_0.item(0), x_0.item(1))
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What if I wanted to get the scalar value from the second row, second column of a 2x2 numpy matrix?

Comment: `x_0.item(i, j)` also works. But why don't you use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix`?